# Intellij 2016.2 keyboard scrolling slow on linux gnome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, gnome

I'm facing an annoying problem on Intellij 2016.2 community on ubuntu gnome: scrolling on editor window is too slow with keyboard arrows, when I reach the end of visible code the scroll lags.

I've done some changes on the idea.vmoptions like increase memory opts (because I have 16gb ram) but seems not change the behaviour.

here's my idea.vmoptions conf:

```
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=100
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dhidpi=true
```

I have ubuntu gnome 16.04 with hidpi laptop screen

any idea? thanks

Comment: I seem to have similar issue (on XUbuntu 16.04) - is it more noticeable with pgup / pg down? I don't have hidpi though..

Comment: the scroll lags even on right/left side...I've noticed it comparing on same version on macbook. Scrolling on macbook is far more smooth and natural without any extra tuning